# Easyphp & SwiftMailer 4.3 Unable to send message (PHP / SWIFT)

Tags: php, apache, ssl, swiftmailer, easyphp

I've been trying to send an email using SwiftMailer and a gmail account, but it shows me the famous referrer that no SSL is detected

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #1351731711]' in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\Swift-4.3.1\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:259 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\Swift-4.3.1\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(64): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() #1 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\Swift-4.3.1\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(115): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\Swift-4.3.1\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(80): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\test.php(19): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\Swift-4.3.1\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 259

I've been going on Google, overhere and in my php.ini, and apache configuration file, tutorials both in French and English and nothing seems to work the closest I got thought is making the licence files with cmd commands...
Please instruct me and insight my ignorance with a step by step method or tutorial

I'm on : Windows 8, using EasyPhP 12.1 Apache 2 with a PHP 5 interrupter,  php_curl is enabled and the Swift-4.3.1 folder contains the swiftMailer package

THANK YOU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable your `php_openssl` module in your **php.ini** when you try to connect to a SSL connection.